# How to make sure that name fits in the designated space on the website

Tags: html, css, web

So I am building a quick small website. In the website, when the user is logging in, the website asks for the name. In my database, I have allocated a VARCHAR(255) for the username and restrict the first name to 50 characters when the user is logging in. However, I have no clue how to make sure that the any of the names being displayed on the website don't overflow their designated container. I don't want to use `word-wrap: break-word` and `overflow: auto` because I don't want to break up the name or hide part of it. I just want to make sure it fits in its container. How can I make sure that it fits? Thanks in advance.

Yang

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not want to break up the name or hide parts of under any circumstances you have three alternative paths to consider, as far as I can see:

1. Size the designated container element so that it can fit the widest possible 50 character strings. You can get good benchmark for example by creating `<span>` element with identical font family size containing 50 `W` characters that should be in most fonts among the widest letter characters. Then inspect the the element in browser inspector to get the maximum width. Maybe finally round up that width in your CSS for the container to be on the safe side and take into account any possible paddings etc. that reduce the inner width.
2. Make the designated container element width increase dynamically when needed with CSS or Javascript.
3. Make font size in the designated container element decrease dynamically when needed with Javascript.